# Copy from one workbook and paste into another

Tags: excel, vba

I have written the following code and continually see `pastespecial method of class has failed`. I have tried to overcome this issue, but nothing seems to work. I am trying to copy an entire sheet from one workbook, and paste it into another:

```
Set x = Workbooks.Open(" path to copying book ")
Workbooks.Open(" path to copying book ").Activate
Range("A1").Select
'Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Set y = Workbooks.Open("path to pasting book")
Workbooks.Open("Path to pasting book").Activate

With y
    Sheets("sheetname").Cells.Select
    Range("A1").PasteSpecial
    'Sheets("sheetname").PasteSpecial
    .Close
End With

With x
    .Close
End With
```

Comment: Try `.Sheets("sheetname")...` and `.Range("A1").PasteSpecial` if that doesn't work, re-work your code to avoid `Select` method, it is clunky, hard to interpret, resource intensive, and inefficient :)

Answer (score 83, accepted):

This should do it, let me know if you have trouble with it:

```
Sub foo()
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook

'## Open both workbooks first:
Set x = Workbooks.Open(" path to copying book ")
Set y = Workbooks.Open(" path to destination book ")

'Now, copy what you want from x:
x.Sheets("name of copying sheet").Range("A1").Copy

'Now, paste to y worksheet:
y.Sheets("sheetname").Range("A1").PasteSpecial

'Close x:
x.Close

End Sub
```

Alternatively, you could just:

```
Sub foo2()
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook

'## Open both workbooks first:
Set x = Workbooks.Open(" path to copying book ")
Set y = Workbooks.Open(" path to destination book ")

'Now, transfer values from x to y:
y.Sheets("sheetname").Range("A1").Value = x.Sheets("name of copying sheet").Range("A1") 

'Close x:
x.Close

End Sub
```

To extend this to the entire sheet:

```
With x.Sheets("name of copying sheet").UsedRange
    'Now, paste to y worksheet:
    y.Sheets("sheet name").Range("A1").Resize( _
        .Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
End With
```

And yet another way, store the value as a variable and write the variable to the destination:

```
Sub foo3()
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook
Dim vals as Variant

'## Open both workbooks first:
Set x = Workbooks.Open(" path to copying book ")
Set y = Workbooks.Open(" path to destination book ")

'Store the value in a variable:
vals = x.Sheets("name of sheet").Range("A1").Value

'Use the variable to assign a value to the other file/sheet:
y.Sheets("sheetname").Range("A1").Value = vals 

'Close x:
x.Close

End Sub
```

The last method above is usually the fastest for most applications, but do note that for very large datasets (100k rows) it's observed that the Clipboard actually outperforms the array dump:

[Copy/PasteSpecial vs Range.Value = Range.Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45019541/copy-pastespecial-vs-range-value-range-value/45020388#45020388)

That said, there are *other* considerations than just speed, and it may be the case that the performance hit on a large dataset is worth the tradeoff, to avoid interacting with the Clipboard.

Comment: David that you very much for your help! Unfortunately I am receiving a compound error saying "Method or data member not found" and it is highlighting the first ".Sheets" line from which it is trying to copy. Do you know what may be the problem?

Comment: The error happens at this: `Sheets("name of copying sheet").Range("A1").Copy` ??  Can you double-check that you've copied it correctly and it doesn't contain any typos?  I can't think of any reason you'd get that error (even typos should raise a *different* error message) but try two alternative methods also added to my answer, above.

Comment: I have used the second method you suggested and it works perfectly! thank you very much!

Comment: David, how would I extend this equating of cells to equating entire sheets?

Comment: I added that info, above.

Comment: Set x = Application.Workbooks.Open("xpath")
        Set y = Application.Workbooks.Open("ypath")
        
  With WorkbookCopyingtoo.Sheets("sheet").UsedRange
     WorkbookCopyingFrom.Sheets("Sheet").Range("A1").Resize(.Rows.Count, Columns.Count) = .Value
  End With

Comment: This is how I have it David and I am still getting errors saying subscript out of range. Can you see what the problem is?

Comment: As I said before the only thing I can think of that would cause that error on a range assignment is a worksheet name that doesn't exist. You're on your own. Now, since I've answered this particular problem for you, please consider marking the answer as "accepted", if you're having trouble with another error (i.e., your `subscript out of range` error), please post a new question with that problem.

Comment: @DavidZemens how to copy from a workbook to new workbook for specific range? 

`Set endUserWS = Workbooks.Add

    
Copy Columns 1 by 1
i = 0
For Each col In colNames
    On Error GoTo colNotFound
    colN = destWS.Rows(1).Find(col, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False).Column
 
    If colN <> -1 Then
    endUserWS.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(2, i)).Value = destWS.Range(Cells(2, colN), Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, colN).End(xlUp).Row, colN))
      
    End If
i = i + 1
Next col
`
is it fine? 
I get blank cells in new workbook. Values dont get copied.

Comment: the code you suggested works but i get a popup saying" there is a large amount of information on the clipboard,..." how do i avoid getting this popup

Comment: Use `Application.DisplayAlerts=False` before closing the file (and remember to reset it to True after closing the file)

Answer (score 6):

You copied using Cells.
If so, no need to PasteSpecial since you are copying data at exactly the same format.
Here's your code with some fixes.

```
Dim x As Workbook, y As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

Set x = Workbooks.Open("path to copying book")
Set y = Workbooks.Open("path to pasting book")

Set ws1 = x.Sheets("Sheet you want to copy from")
Set ws2 = y.Sheets("Sheet you want to copy to")

ws1.Cells.Copy ws2.cells
y.Close True
x.Close False
```

If however you really want to paste special, use a dynamic Range("Address") to copy from.
Like this:

```
ws1.Range("Address").Copy: ws2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
y.Close True
x.Close False
```

Take note of the `:` colon after the `.Copy` which is a `Statement Separating` character.
Using `Object.PasteSpecial` requires to be executed in a new line.
Hope this gets you going.

Comment: Will this update the `"Sheet you want to copy to"`  if  `"Sheet you want to copy from"` is getting updated ?

Comment: Yes, I think it should @Greencolor.