# VBA: Unable to reference Range in another sheet

Tags: excel, paste, vba

This is my first post, so please provide any feedback about my approach to presenting the problem.

I'm building a sub that (ultimately) is supposed to copy a range from one sheet ("Sandbox") to another ("Master"). The steps are:

- Identify the selected rows
- Loop through the Sandbox rows, determining whether to find a matching Master row or add as a new end-row in Master
- Copy the *values only* from each selected Sandbox row to the appropriate Master row

The error pops with the setting the range for the PasteSpecial function. That line consistently gives a "1004 (Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed" message.

Here's the code :

```
Sub UpdateMaster()

    Dim currentSelection As Range
    Set currentSelection = Selection

    Dim sheetSB As Worksheet
    Set sheetSB = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sandbox")
    Dim sheetMaster As Worksheet
    Set sheetMaster = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master")

    Dim lastTargetRow As Integer
    lastTargetRow = sheetMaster.Range("IDRange").End(xlDown).Row + 1
    Dim startingTargetColumn As Integer
    startingTargetColumn = sheetMaster.Range("IDRange").Column

    Dim thisID As String
    Dim thisStatus As String

    For Each thisrow In currentSelection.Rows
        ' Capture the current ID value
        thisID = Cells(thisrow.Row, Range("IDRange").Column).Value
        ' Capture the current Status value
        thisStatus = Cells(thisrow.Row, Range("NewRange").Column).Value

        ' If the row has no ID...
        If thisID = "" Then
            ' ...do nothing
          ' If the row is flagged as new...
          ElseIf thisStatus = "New" Then
            '...identify the first blank row, and set all data columns to be copied
            Range(Cells(thisrow.Row, Range("IDRange").Column), Cells(thisrow.Row, Range("LastSandboxColumn")).Column).Copy _
              Destination:=sheetMaster.Range(lastTargetRow, startingTargetColumn)

            ' Increment the next available last row by 1
            lastTargetRow = lastTargetRow + 1
          Else
          ' Otherwise, find the corresponding row and set the non-ID columns to be copied
            Dim sourceColumn1 As Integer, sourceColumn2 As Integer
            Dim targetRow As Integer, targetColumn As Integer
            Dim matchRow As Integer

            sourceColumn1 = Range("IDRange").Column + 1
            sourceColumn2 = Range("LastSandboxColumn").Column

            targetRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(thisID, sheetMaster.Range("IDRange"), 0)
            targetColumn = startingTargetColumn + 1

            Range(Cells(thisrow.Row, sourceColumn1), Cells(thisrow.Row, sourceColumn2)).Copy
            Range(sheetMaster.Cells(targetRow, targetColumn)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

The error is happening on the last line:

```
Range(sheetMaster.Cells(targetRow, targetColumn)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Inexplicably, the following seems to work:

```
Range(Cells(thisrow.Row, sourceColumn1), Cells(thisrow.Row, sourceColumn2)).Copy _
  Destination:=Range(sheetMaster.Cells(targetRow, targetColumn))
```

Unfortunately, I want only the values; bringing over formulas and formatting will screw up other behavior in the sheet.

I have tried many variations, but essentially it will not allow me to create a range, referencing Master, if I use Cells().

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Try `sheetMaster.Cells(targetRow, targetColumn).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do:

```
sheetMaster.Cells(targetRow, targetColumn).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

An error could occur with this, if the `sheetMaster` isn't the ActiveSheet at runtime:

```
Range(sheetMaster.Cells(targetRow, targetColumn).PasteSpecial) xlPasteValues
```

Also note, for this problem:

> Unfortunately, I want only the values; bringing over formulas and formatting will screw up other behavior in the sheet.

You can get the range's `.Value` as an array, and write it directly to the other sheet without invoking either `Copy` or `Paste/PasteSpecial` methods. The answer below shows several methods of copying/pasting from one workbook to another, but could easily be modified for sheet-to-sheet transfer, instead.

[Copy from one workbook and paste into another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19351832/copy-from-one-workbook-and-paste-into-another/19352099#19352099)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Just for clarification: I've tried "sheetMaster.Range(...", and it rejects it. If I wanted to act on a Range in another sheet, how would I do that?

Comment: Sorry, one more thought: I found that using "Range(sm.Cells(x, y), sm.Cells(x, y)" DOES work (actually using a duplicate start/end set of Cells references). Strange behavior...