# Excel VBA, searching values in specific cells in a named range

Tags: excel, named-ranges, vba

I'm rather new to all of this and have looked everywhere.

I have a named range "Ruptures" (N14:P60) in sheet 7 in which I would like to find in column P values greater than 0 and paste corresponding cells N:P in sheet 9 F:H. I can't seem to search only column P.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
Dim cell As Variant
Dim count As Long
count = 0

With Sheet7

Set Rng = Sheet7.Range("Ruptures")

For Each cell In Rng

'But I only want to check cells from the P column (this is where I am stumped)

If cell.Value > 0 Then
Range(cell.Offset(0, -2), cell.Offset(0, 0)).Copy

Sheet9.Activate
Range("F14", "H14").Offset(count, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

count = count + 1

Sheet7.Activate

Next

End With

End If

End Sub
```

Thank so much in advance and have a great day !   :)

Ursula

Comment: It looks like your `End If` should be before your `Next`, for an immediate glance

Answer (score 0):

This is iterating over the entire (multi-column) range:

```
Set Rng = Sheet7.Range("Ruptures")
For Each cell In Rng
```

You can limit this to the third column using this:

```
For Each cell in Rng.Columns(3)
```

I would also simplify the copy/paste [to avoid unnecessary worksheet `Activate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) and to use direct `Value` assignment from one range to the other (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19351832/copy-from-one-workbook-and-paste-into-another/19352099#19352099) for more detail as well). And as noted in the comments, your `Next` statement can't be inside the `If` block:

```
For Each cell in Rng.Columns(3)

    If cell.Value > 0 Then
        Sheet9.Range("F14", "H14").Offset(count, 0).Value = Range(cell.Offset(0, -2), cell.Offset(0, 0)).Value
        count = count + 1
    End If

Next
```

This could be further refined using `Resize` methods:

```
For Each cell in Rng.Columns(3)

    If cell.Value > 0 Then
        Sheet9.Range("F14").Offset(count).Resize(1,3).Value = cell.Offset(0,-2).Resize(1,3).Value
        count = count + 1
    End If

Next
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It didn't work for me probably because of all the other code involved. But, thanks to your answer, I was able to think things through differently and was able to make this project work. Thanks again!  :)