# VBA Excel copy cell range to external workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Previously I was dealing with the query below:

[VBA Excel taking control of the cells on the another workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61481768/vba-excel-taking-control-of-the-cells-on-the-another-workbook)

regarding copying the data from my active workbook to some external workbook.

Now I would like to do an analog copy, but not as a single cell, but as a range.

[image]

My code looks like this:

```
  Sub Splicing()

  Dim PoP As String, SN As String
  Dim Fibre As Range

  Dim newbook As Workbook
  Dim fs As Worksheet

  Set fw = Sheets("Frontsheet")
  'name = fw.Range("AA9")
  name = fw.Range("D18")
  name2 = fw.Range("D38")
  custom_name = name & " - Splicing As-build_v." & name2 & ".0"

  PoP = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Frontsheet").Range("D10").Value
  SN = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Frontsheet").Range("D12").Value

  Fibre = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Fibre Drop Release Sheet").Range("A2:H20").Value

  Path = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Splicing Template_V1.0.xlsm"
  Set newbook = Workbooks.Open(Path)

  newbook.Sheets("Frontsheet").Cells(10, 4).Value = PoP
  newbook.Sheets("Frontsheet").Cells(12, 4).Value = SN


  newbook.Sheets("Fibre drop release sheet").Cells(3, 2).Value = Fibre


  Path = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & custom_name & ".xlsm"

  'Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=Path, FileFormat:=52


  End Sub
```

The debugger shows line Fibre =  and says: **Object variable or With block variable not set**.

I tried also the other solution presented here:

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3084-excel-copy-range-to-new-workbook.html

and here

[VBA Copying Excel Range to Different Workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43123543/vba-copying-excel-range-to-different-workbook)

and here

http://debugvba.com/copy-data-from-one-sheet-to-another-workbook-vba-excel-debugvba/

but these codes don't match to my example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues:

```
Dim Fibre As Range
...
Fibre = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Fibre Drop Release Sheet").Range("A2:H20").Value
```

Change to

```
Dim Fibre As Variant
```

Then if you're using value transfer, the destination and source should be the same size:

```
newbook.Sheets("Fibre drop release sheet").Range("B3:I21").Value = Fibre
```

If you don't want to hard-code the address `B3:I21`, then `Resize` is useful to get the destination to the same size as the source.

```
newbook.Sheets("Fibre drop release sheet").Cells(3, 2).Resize(Ubound(Fibre, 1), Ubound(Fibre, 2)).Value = Fibre
```