# VBA - annoying copy and paste issue

Tags: vba, excel

I am struggling with this code and I don't understand why it's causing an issue.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("B1:E" & lastrow).Copy
        ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        ActiveSheet.Name = startday & "_" & startmonth & "_" & startyear
```

This keeps generating an error on line three.

Originally I simply had "Range("B1").pastespecial" etc, but this was pasting into another open workbook, even though it was not the active sheet.

I have tried about 70 or 80 different possible alternative approaches, and I cannot get it to do something which I regard as fairly simple - namely copy this range and paste them as values in the same location, in the same sheet.

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros

Comment: Also relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19351832/copy-from-one-workbook-and-paste-into-another/19352099#19352099

Comment: I'm aware of the importance of avoiding select, yes.

I am doing things which are not proper because I had already tried all the obviously "correct" things.

Comment: But the key is you should *also* be avoiding reliance on `ActiveSheet` :)  It's *always* better to explicitly declare and assign worksheet variables, rather than rely on the user to keep the appropriate sheet *active* throughout runtime.

Comment: show your `lastrow` definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for the excellent replies.

I identified the cause, although I don't fully understand the underlying reason for the problem.

I was taking the approach of copying a worksheet from one workbook to a new workbook, and then copying and pasting the target range (including formulae) on this new worksheet as values.

When this didn't work, I tried the method suggested by @David Zemens, but this didn't work either.

It seems to me as though the issue was that the formulae in the new sheet were referencing cells in the original worksheet, and that for some reason (said reason being the bit I don't currently understand), this meant that VBA did not like it when I tried to convert them to values and/or copy and paste as values.

Once I adopted the alternative approach of getting VBA to create a new workbook, and then pasting the content of the original sheet in that new book as values, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

`ActiveSheet` can cause problems, [*have a read*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) about how to avoid using `Select` and `Active...` elements like `ActiveSheet`.

Essentially, just make sure you fully qualify each reference to a `Worksheet` by also specifying which `Workbook` the worksheet is in.

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SomeWorksheet").Range("B1:E" & lastrow).Copy
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("AnotherWorksheet").Range("B1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("YetAnotherWorksheet").Name = startday & "_" & startmonth & "_" & startyear
```

---

If all your actions are related to the same worksheet, you can simplify things by using the `With` token:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SomeWorksheet")    
    .Range("B1:E" & lastrow).Copy
    .Range("B1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    .Name = startday & "_" & startmonth & "_" & startyear
End With
```

Comment: Hi,

I tried: 

with BookZ.sheets("Sheet2")
.range(B1:E" & lastrow).copy
.Range("B1").pastespecial xlpastevalues

This generated an automation error - "the object invoked has disconnected from its clients", etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to paste values in to the *same* sheet, then you need only do:

```
With ActiveSheet.Range("B1:E" & lastrow)
    .Value = .Value
End With
ActiveSheet.Name = startday & "_" & startmonth & "_" & startyear
```

Preferably, I would define *which* sheet, just so there's no ambiguity:

```
With Workbooks("name of workbook").Worksheets("name of sheet").Range("B1:E" & lastRow)
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

This takes the `.Value` property of the range/array and writes it back to the sheet. There is no need to copy or paste anything, and the result will be that only the *values* remain (i.e., all formula references will be wiped out).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. 

This is causing Excel to crash.  Do you have any idea why that might be?

Comment: @Statsanalyst what's the value of `lastrow`?

Comment: @@David Zemens 46.

Comment: That shouldn't cause any error @Statsanalyst can you provide the full code you're using? Are you sure it's crashing on *this part of the code* and not somewhere else? Are there any event-handlers in this worksheet which might be triggering an infinite loop or something?