# Copy-paste between workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to copy-paste a table row by row from one Workbook1 to Workbook2 ( on an interval of time ). 
In Workbook2 every row copied has its own sheet, the next copy-paste is gonna be on the next empty row. 
( in the picture that I've attached Audi row is gonna have its own sheet, where every update is gonna go in the next empty row, the same for the others), here is the code that I tried only for one row of table but it doesn`t works:

```
Sub Updateeee()
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:15"), "lalala"
End Sub

Sub lalala()
Workbooks("Workbook1.xls").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:R2").Copy
ActiveCellRow.Offset(1, 0).Activate
Workbooks("Workbook2.xls").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Paste
Call Updateeee
End Sub
```

[Table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yudwS.jpg)

Comment: Did it work? What is your question?

Comment: Hi @JacobH, it doesn't work, I just edited now the question, thank you!

Comment: Hi Amy, please consider the link at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19351832/copy-from-one-workbook-and-paste-into-another. It has multiple solutions for this.

Comment: Thank you @StillNestling, I'm gonna have a look there!

Comment: @StillNestling I've tried first two codes and it doesn't copy, I double checked them too...

Comment: I figured it out, I just have to find a way that next copy-paste to go on the next empty row...

Answer (score 1):

To find next empty row:

```
 rowCount =  wbDest.Sheets("Data").rows.count
 NextEmptyRow = wbDest.Sheets("Data").Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

To paste you may use the solution provided by @Moosli or a lot of examples are given at [Copy from one workbook and paste into another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19351832/copy-from-one-workbook-and-paste-into-another) including the solution given here so you may use the the one that suits your needs.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
Workbooks("Name.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Range(Cells(6, 8), Cells(6, 9)).Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range(Cells(6, 8), Cells(6, 9))
```

Or something like this,

```
Dim wbSour As Workbook
Dim wbDest As Workbook

'Open WB's
Set wbSour = Workbooks.Open("wbSource.xls")
Set wbDest = Workbooks.Open("wbDestination.xls")

'Copy from one to the other
wbDest.Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1").Value = wbSour.Sheets("sheet2").Range("A1") 

'Close Source file:
wbSour .Close
```

Comment: There is some space between "wbSour" and  ".Sheets." (and similarly) that should be removed.