# What is the "correct" way to copy-paste data in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, performance, copy-paste

**What is the "correct" way to copy-paste data in VBA in Excel?**

Now, at least to my knowledge, these three are the only available methods:

1. the *(`Range`)* [**`.Copy([Destination])`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-copy-method-excel) method
2. the *(`Worksheet`)* [**`.Paste([Destination, Link])`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-paste-method-excel) method
3. and the *(`Range`)* [**`.PasteSpecial([Paste], [Operation], [SkipBlanks], [Transpose])`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-pastespecial-method-excel) method

---

Now, I did my research, these are the **pros & cons** of **`.Copy([Destination])`**  and the **`.Paste([Destination, Link])`** method, least those, that I can think of:

#### pros:

- allows us to paste data in the same expression as copying *(code-readability I guess..?)*

#### cons:

- Cell references are a complete no go!
- Your formatting  and formulas might get messed up
- If the range overlaps it will display a prompt, effectively stopping macro dead in its tracks     *(that's a huge bummer especially if you're trying to automize something)*
- Worse yet, if you press `Cancel` on the prompt, it will throw an `Error`** (unless handled)

---

On the other side of the coin, **`.PasteSpecial()`**

#### pros:

- `PasteSpecial()` allows us to paste a specific part of range!
- it allows us to specify what type of paste we want to do
- has an inbuilt `skipBlanks` and `transpose` functionality
- **is not "so" `Error`-prone!**

and I struggled to come up with any, but:

#### cons:

- a bit more characters to write?

---

Now, that leads me to believe, that the `Destination` argument of `.Copy()` method should essentially be ignored and `PasteSpecial()` should be always used instead.

**Is there ever an occassion where usage of it might be preferable over `.PasteSpecial()`? Or should `PasteSpecial()` be the norm for every copy-paste operation?**

Comment: You forgot the assign value directly: `Range().Value = Range().Value`

Comment: Aren't you ignoring the [Worksheet.Paste Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-paste-method-excel)?

Comment: @ScottCraner I did think about it, but that's not really copy-pasting, but more of a typical pointer referencing, hence I decided not to include it in my question. I didn't want to open a book to the "what counts as copy-pasting" discussion.

Comment: @Jeeped yes, I did infact forget it. Though *(luckily for me)* I feel like the `.Paste` method contains very similar design flaws (if you could call it that way) as the `.Copy` method. Edited accordingly, thanks for the quick notice

Comment: With `PasteSpecial` it will throw an error if nothing is in the clipboard, so I think from my experience it needs error more handling. (especially if you are creating a Crlt+Shift+V shortcut to paste values!)

Comment: "to settle the discussion once and for all" - um... good luck with that!  I see nothing wrong with `.Copy()` if that fits the need.

Comment: @TimWilliams okay I admit, the more stylistic writer in me got carried away with that statement, while it sound cool, it has no rightful place in that question. Edited it out.

Comment: I almost never use `PasteSpecial`: most of the time `Copy` does exactly what I need, and is more concise.

Comment: if all you want is values, then nothing will beat performance of direct value assignment. This is the last example in my accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19351832/copy-from-one-workbook-and-paste-into-another/19352099#19352099

Comment: I have to admit, trying to think of where/when I've used either in the past and the answer is, I rarely use either.  I usually just copy the range to a variant, process the data and dump it back.  If I need formatting, I'll do that after, but en masse.

Comment: NB that `Paste` also pastes formatting, number formats, etc. So obviously if you need to preserve *all* properties of the range, `Paste` is the preferred solution IMO. If you need values only, then `Range.Value = array_of_values` is ideal. If you need some combination of values & formats, then I would combine the direct value assignment *and* `PasteSpecial` (the latter for formats, etc.)

Comment: This is basically asking for opinions, as that is what you will get.  I like A because of Y and dislike B because of Z

Comment: @ScottCraner I see what you're aiming at and also why you would interpret it in that way, but I disagree. I did explcitly try to point out measurable facts about each method and I'm hoping for the discussion to be about **a) what is more efficient** and **b) less error prone** I do understand there is a merit of personal preference to it, but I feel like there **lacks even any sort of comparison between these methods, be it on StackOverflow or even the internet** which could prove to be useful **and help users (myself included) pick their own personal preference, based on the facts served!**

Comment: @DavidZemens "nothing will beat performance of direct value assignment" I thought so too, but then I semi-recently was [proven otherwise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45020388/1188513); given *very large* data sets, I was surprised to find out that direct assignment was effectively beaten by the clipboard.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon that's very good to know!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This isn't about readability or how many characters you're typing. It's about *what you need to achieve*.

In other words, it's absolutely not subjective or opinion-based, and like pretty much everything else in programming...

## #ItDepends.

If you're using Excel and copy-pasting cells around, do you <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> or use *paste special*?

Depends what you need to do.

- If you mean to copy a cell, its value, formats, data validations, borders, etc.; then `.Paste [Destination]` is your best friend. That's the programmatic equivalent of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>... Equivalent to PasteSpecial/All, which is overkill since `.Paste [Destination]` already does everything you need it to do in this case.

  > *Cell references are a complete no go!*

  Absolutely. Hard-coded cell references are bad. `.Paste [Destination]` doesn't force you to do that anyway, so the point is moot.

  > *If the range overlaps it will display a prompt, effectively stopping macro dead in its tracks*

  Copy and paste ranges cannot overlap, period. You'll get that prompt through `.PasteSpecial` too.
- If you mean to copy a cell's `Value`, **but not** its formats, data validations, borders, etc.; then `.PasteSpecial` is definitely a better idea, since that's the programmatic equivalent of going *paste special / values* - except it's probably more efficient to just assign the cell's `Value` with what you want (no need to round-trip to/from the clipboard); OTOH if you **do** mean to paste formats, or data validations, or whatnot, then this is probably the easiest way.

`Paste` doesn't "mess up" formats. It does exactly what it means to do. `Paste` and `PasteSpecial` are **not** equivalents. Use the right tool for the job. They are literally the programmatic equivalents of "paste" and "paste special", respectively - if you're in Excel and systematically going "paste special", you'll get your stuff done. But every time you do that to "paste all", you're working harder than you need to be.

`PasteSpecial` looks like a nice hammer, but not everything is a nail. When you can avoid a clipboard write, it's generally a good idea to avoid it... but then again, [if you're dealing with huge data sets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45020388/1188513) (think 100K+ cells), it's possible that it performs better than just assigning the values.

That said:

> @ScottCraner I did think about it, but that's not really copy-pasting, but more of a typical pointer referencing, hence I decided not to include it in my question. I didn't want to open a book to the "what counts as copy-pasting" discussion.

That is wrong. `.Range(foo).Value = .Range(bar).Value` isn't "typical pointer referencing". It's literally taking the values of `foo` into a 2D variant array, and dumping that 2D variant array onto `bar`, overwriting the previously held values. As such, it absolutely is a completely valid alternative to hitting the clipboard - but you'll need to test and compare against `Copy`+`PasteSpecial` to see if that's the best (/most efficient) solution for your situation:

> ```
> Testing with 1500000 cells (100000 rows)
> Pasting from clipboard, single operation: 324.21875ms
> Setting cell values, single operation:    1496.09375ms
>
>
> Testing with 150 cells (10 rows)
> Pasting from clipboard, single operation: 11.71875ms
> Setting cell values, single operation:    3.90625ms
> Pasting from clipboard, iterative:        1773.4375ms
> Setting cell values, iterative:           105.46875ms
> ```

Comment: to me, the fact that `It Depends` is the answer, indicates the question is not right for this forum.  You are correct that classifying it as an opinion is probably wrong, but it is then too broad a subject for this forum.  Again, this is my opinion.  But I like the answer.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for in an answer. Also Im glad you share the same reasoning when it comes to question being opiniom based - although I should have probably done better job explaining in the original question. Wish I could upvote more than once here!