# Select range and copy

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy data from one file to another. The range changes everytime I download the source file.
I created a macro to copy from one workbook to another, but is not working.

```
Sub Copy_Method()

Dim lRow As Long
Dim lCol As Long

lRow = Workbooks("Active Dealers with State.xlsx").Worksheets("Active Dealers With State").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lCol = Workbooks("Active Dealers with State.xlsx").Worksheets("Active Dealers With State").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Workbooks("Active Dealers with State.xlsx").Worksheets("Active Dealers With State").Range("A4", Cells(lRow, lCol).Select).Copy _
    Workbooks("Working Sheet.xlsx").Worksheets("Active Dealer with State").Range("A4")

End Sub
```

What is the issue here? I want to copy the entire data from Active Dealers with State workbook to the Working sheet file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy from one workbook and paste into another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19351832/copy-from-one-workbook-and-paste-into-another)

Answer (score 1):

Some more variables and being more explicit about your range/cells references should improve things:

```
Sub Copy_Method()

    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lCol As Long
    Dim wsSource as worksheet, wsDest as worksheet

    Set wsSource = Workbooks("Active Dealers with State.xlsx").Worksheets("Active Dealers With State")
    Set wsDest = Workbooks("Working Sheet.xlsx").Worksheets("Active Dealer with State")


    lRow = wsSource.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lCol = wsSource.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    'note qualified Cells reference below...
    With wsSource
        .Range(.Range("A4"), .Cells(lRow, lCol)).Copy wsDest.Range("A4")
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: On which line ?

Comment: See my edits above - missed deleting an extra `Select`

Comment: Still just the first column, i.e. column A is only being copied

Comment: What's the value of `lCol`?  Add `Debug.Print lRow, lCol` and see what is output (in the Immediate pane in the VB editor)  In your question you indicate the headers are in the first row: if that's not the case then you'll need to make changes...  E.g.  `lCol = orgWS.Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should be using the copy/paste as that is very inefficient.  You could just set the values equal to each other

```
Sub Copy_Method()
    Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long
    Dim orgWS As Worksheet, newWS As Worksheet

    Set orgWS = Workbooks("Active Dealers with State.xlsx").Worksheets("Active Dealers With State")
    Set newWS = Workbooks("Working Sheet.xlsx").Worksheets("Active Dealer with State")

    lRow = orgWS.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lCol = orgWS.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    newWS.Range(newWS.Cells(4, 1), newWS.Cells(lRow, lCol)) = orgWS.Range(orgWS.Cells(4, 1), orgWS.Cells(lRow, lCol)).Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Just the first column is being copied, there are two columns with the values in it

Comment: are the values in the first row?  The code pulls through every row and column for me.  lCol looks at the last column from row 1.  If it's in a different row then you would just need to change the 1 to whatever column you want.

Comment: *> "using copy paste is very inefficient comapred to setting values"* - [Not necessarily always true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51826865/what-is-the-correct-way-to-copy-paste-data-in-vba)

Comment: if the row number is dynamic and you can use this `lCol = orgWS.UsedRange.Columns(orgWS.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Column`

Comment: the content starts from A3, however the third row is the heading part. Therefore, the data starts from A4 and I have multiple files from where data needs to be copied. One file has 4 columns, one has 10 and the other one has 2 columns. This code I tried on the one with 2 columns, but only the first column data (VERTICAL) is being copied.