# Copy data from different excel files from different folders in another file

Tags: vba

I have one folder containing subfolders and that subfolders are having .xlsx files.
Read data from these .xlsx files and paste it into another excel file.

How can I read data from multiple files?

Comment: Probably duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19351832/copy-from-one-workbook-and-paste-into-another

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy from one workbook and paste into another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19351832/copy-from-one-workbook-and-paste-into-another)