# How to reset the active cell to the cell that the Macro starts on?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to make a Macro that takes data from fixed cells in another sheet that I update and inputs the data into another sheet. Everyday I put new data into the source sheet and it will be transferred into the second sheet as that days data (one row). This requires the original cell I run the macro from to be the fixed point of reference. How do I reset the active cell the cell that I hit the Macro keystroke from?

I have tried Startcell = activecell or things of that type but they have not yielded results. I'm not good with VBA so it could have been a formatting error that resulted in this not working.

```
Sub Macro15()
'
' Macro15 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+Q
'
    Sheets("MACRO (insert data)").Select
    Range("G4:Q4").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Jun-2019").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("MACRO (insert data)").Select
    Range("W4:AG5").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Jun-2019").Select
    Range("C42").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("O10:Y10").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Startcell.Offset(0, 11).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```

If someone could help me just return the active cell to the start cell after "Range("O10:Y10").Select" and "Selection.Copy" that would be great.

Comment: First you need to capture the (initially)  active cell. Do that with a variable. At the end of your code, you can then do `<your_variable_name>.Select` Related: [Avoid Activate/Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba/) wherever possible. None of your macro actually *requires* anything to be Selected, so this is an X/Y problem: you desire to return the initial selection, but that's only because you're altering the selection needlessly during runtime :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm attempting now to remove all the activate and selections, but how would I store the initially active cell as a variable using Dim?

Comment: `Dim startRange as Range` and then `Set startRange = ActiveCell`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, untested. Note that after `copyRange` is first assigned, it's unclear where you need that data pasted/transferred. You'll need to update `destSheet.Range(" ??? ")` to refer to a proper address rather than `" ??? "`.

Note that we don't select or activate anything. We make use of the fact that *Values* from a range can be directly assigned to another range of equal size, simply by doing something like `rng2.Value = rng1.Value`. More information on copying values between workbooks/worksheets: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19351832/copy-from-one-workbook-and-paste-into-another/19352099#19352099).

I've declared relevant variables which should make the code easier to maintain (e.g., there is now only ONE place where you need to change worksheet names in the future months, etc.)

```
Dim StartCell as Range
Dim copyRange as Range
Dim dataSheet as Worksheet   '## MACRO (insert data)
Dim destSheet as Worksheet   '## Jun-2019
Set dataSheet = Sheets("MACRO (insert data)")
Set destSheet = Sheets("Jun-2019")

Set StartCell = ActiveCell

'First, copy G4:Q4 values
Set copyRange = dataSheet.Range("G4:Q4")
' Update the ??? with the destination for this data from G4:Q4
destSheet.Range(" ??? ").Resize(copyRange.Rows.Count, copyRange.Columns.Count).Value = copyRange.Value

'Second, copy W4:AG5 values:
Set copyRange = dataSheet.Range("W4:AG5")
destSheet.Range("C42").Resize(copyRange.Rows.Count, copyRange.Columns.Count).Value = copyRange.Value

' ## Now set copy O10:Y10 from Jun-2019 worksheet
Set copyRange = destSheet.Range("O10:Y10")
' Finally put these values in the StartCell area
StartCell.Offset(0,11).Resize(copyRange.Rows.Count, copyRange.Columns.Count).Value = copyRange.Value
End With
```

Comment: Thanks David, one last question and this code has worked great. For that last line of code I want to copy the values and make the formula change based on what cell it is being copied into.

Comment: for example, Cell A3 = A2+A1 but I want that formula to copy into B3 as B3= B2+B1.

Comment: That sounds like a new/separate question. If this has solved the immediate question from your original post, consider marking it as accepted. Cheers.