# How do I use pasteSpecial

Tags: excel, vba

I dont seem to be able to use PasteSpecial / know where to add it. I want to cut and paste some date (date, name, job-done etc) from a Job input sheet (the fields will clear after the Submit button is pressed) into another sheet, i want the destination sheet to move down a row each time so it collects all the info in 1 sheet. My macro does work and i have assigned it to the submit button but it also moves the cell format can anyone advise what i need to do ?
PS I am a complete VBA beginner..!

my current code is below, I also tried using range instead of copy and paste which resolved the problem of the format moving with the data but then i could not make it move down a row on the target sheet, is range a better solution to copy and paste ?
thanks in advance to anyone who can help

```
Sub submit()
'
' Submit Macro
'

'
    Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
    Dim lDestLastRow As Long

    Set wsCopy = Workbooks("HEATHER.xlsx").Worksheets("JOB")
    Set wsDest = Workbooks("HEATHER.xlsx").Worksheets("2019")
    Range("C5:G5").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Sheets("2019").Select
    CopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of `ActiveSheet.Paste`, do `Selection.PasteSpecial`? However, you should really read this on [how/why to avoid relying on Select/Activate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19351832/copy-from-one-workbook-and-paste-into-another/19352099#19352099) on how to copy values only from one workbook/worksheet to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few notes. Try avoid using `.Select` and `.Activate` where you can. You also fail to set `lDestLastRow` in your code. Also not sure how/ why you have `lCopyLastRow`.

See below code (not tested). Should be what you are looking for.

```vb
Sub submit()

    Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
    Dim lDestLastRow As Long

    Set wsCopy = Workbooks("HEATHER.xlsx").Worksheets("JOB")
    Set wsDest = Workbooks("HEATHER.xlsx").Worksheets("2019")

    lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    wsCopy.Range("C5:G5").Copy
    wsDest.Range("A" & lDestLastRow).PasteSpecial xlValues

    wsCopy.Range("C5:G5").ClearContents
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks Dean, thats great and works a treat !! thanks for your quick response. Jim

Comment: @jimjim it's a pleasure. please mark this as your answer to close the question.Regards

Comment: Hi, I wanted to use =TODAY() in the date input field (C5) , currently this get removed every time i run it, is it possible for it not to remove the formula ?

Comment: @jimjim yes, adjust the line with `.ClearContents` to take that into account.