# Copying range from Excel to another Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried to copy Range A1:D7 from Excel_1 to Excel_2
It says Run-time error'9' subscript out of range. What's wrong with it?
Both Excels are located at my onedrive.

```
Option Explicit
Sub copy()
Workbooks("Excel_1.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D7").copy _
Workbooks("Excel_2.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
```

Comment: Are both files open? Do both files have a sheet named Sheet1?

Comment: this is not your problem, but one should not use words that are also current vba functions as their sub names.  I would change `Sub copy()` to something like `Sub MyCopy()` just to avoid confusion.

Comment: That should work as is. You can try doing it a few different ways. See the link below for more ideas of how to do this kind of thing.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19351832/copy-from-one-workbook-and-paste-into-another

Comment: @BigBen Only Excel_1 was open.

Comment: @ScottCraner Good point, i will change it!

Comment: @ASH Thanks, the link you posted is perfect!